# mysqli execute() executing successfully but is not fetching the records

Tags: php, mysqli

I am executing select query using mysqli  ...

```
/** ------------  queries ----------      **/
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM dept");

        if(! $stmt)
        {
            echo "statement not prepared well";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $mysqli->error;
        }

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
         echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
 // add else
 else{
  echo "Query is successfully executed but no result fetch";
   }

        if (!($res = $stmt->get_result())) {
            echo "Getting result set failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
        /** ------------------------------- **/

        #------result ----
        var_dump($res->fetch_all());
        #---------(/result)----
```

My problem is the execute() is working fine but cannot fetch the records ... The table has good amount of data in it ...  it is showing  "Query is successfully executed but no result fetch" and after it `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`

What am I doing wrong .. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the following

```
if (!($res = $stmt->get_result())) {
```

to

```
$res = $stmt->get_result();
if( !$res ) {
```

Or rather to

```
$res = $stmt->get_result();
if( $res->num_rows == 0 ) {
```

---

The error(I didn't notice it earlier) is because

> mysqli_stmt::get_result() is available only with **[`mysqlnd`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php)**.

You need to install/configure it following the [guidelines here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php).

Comment: tried but no change ..

Comment: @new_developer Check the new edit.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong .. ?

You are using mysqli instead of [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Whole your code could be rewritten in these few lines using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dept");
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetchall());
```

without all these numerous `if` and `echo`.
And the difference will be even bigger when you start with prepared statements